# Making WiX Bootstrapper work for bootstrapping with .NET 4.0

Tags: wix, installation, bootstrapper

I've been looking to make my bootstrapper work with installing .NET 4.0 and my own application. I reviewed several blogs and tutorials, but I can't get it to work.

I read in Stack Overflow question *[Initiate / call bootstrapper in WiX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9517144/initiate-call-bootstrapper-in-wix)* that you need to invoke both in the bootstrapper. My bootstrapper only invokes the .NET 4.0 installer. This is the part that should invoke both parts:

```
<Chain>
    <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Redist" />
    <MsiPackage SourceFile="C:\my app.msi" Cache="yes" Visible="no" After="NetFx40Redist"></MsiPackage>
</Chain>
```

It only invokes the packagegroupref. While installing the .NET 4.0 package, it gives an error. It's probably something easy and small, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following works for me:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Bundle Name="Bootstrapper1" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Test" UpgradeCode="5e5f0f1e-58e0-42e5-8306-37533d677535">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" />
    <Variable Name="InstallFolder" Type="string" Value="[ProgramFilesFolder]Test\App"/>

    <Chain>
      <PackageGroupRef Id="NetFx40Web" />
      <MsiPackage
        Id="Setup"
        Compressed="yes"
        SourceFile="$(var.SetupProject1.TargetPath)"
        Vital="yes">
        <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLLOCATION" Value="[InstallFolder]" />
      </MsiPackage>
    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Make sure you add your project and `WixNetFxExtension` as references to the bootstrapper project. I found [this blog](http://neilsleightholm.blogspot.ca/2012/05/wix-burn-tipstricks.html) very helpful.

Comment: thanks for the tip. i added the wixnetfxexstansion but it say's it can't find the  exe file

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean. What is "it" you're referring to? And what exe file are you referring to? The full error message would be helpful.

Comment: This code in the answer.. where does it go? Is it in the wix project file, a wxi, or the main wxs?